# undefined variable 'f' when rendering portions of a form through ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where a Contact has many Leads and a Lead belongs to Profile polymorphically. I successfully rendered the form as such:

```
# _form.html.erb
<%= form_for @lead do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :contact do |builder| %>
      <%= render "contact_fields", :f => builder %>
      <%= render "leads_field", f: f %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

# lead_field.html.erb
<%= f.select :practice_type, PRACTICE_TYPES.collect {|type| [ type, type ] }
<%= f.fields_for :practice do |builder| %>
   <%= render "#{@practice.class.name.underscore}_field", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```

The above works fine with page load. However, a user can select a practice from dropdown menu and then I send ajax request to repopulate the form building an association with that practice:

```
 $('#lead_practice_type').change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/leads/new",
                data: {
                    profile_type : $(this).val()
                },
                dataType: "script"
            });
        });
```

The error occurs in new.js.erb:

```
$("#form_holder").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "leads_field"))%>");
```

I want to only render that partial (if I render whole form, then all their contact information would be erased.). But because that partial contains a local f variable, it blows up:

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `f'
```

I want to maintain the relations between the objects but also update just that one partial. But it appears I cannot do it through the new.js.erb script because when it renders the partial, there is no local variable 'f' passed.

Is there another alternative to achieve what I want?

Comment: Note using render_to_string and passing the data back into the ajax callback function doesn't work either. It produces the same error, since render to string finds f not to be defined in partial as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem difficult to solve on two fronts. First, There is no way you can identify the form builder from the controller action and javascript. Second, although I am quite familiar with the railscasts episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments, in that episode he knew the fields_for to generate at compile time, and therefore he hid the markup in the data field of a link. Unfortunately, in my case I would not know the fields_for the user wants until runtime (when the browser loads and user selects an option).

I also realized that fields_for is important to maintain nice associations for form submission so that the create action would be simply: save the parent resource and it saves its associations.

The best solution I could come up with is as follows.

1) Create ALL the polymorphic associations with fields_for and hide the ones the user doesn't want via a select form field:

```
# template
<div id="runtime-profile">
    <% Lead::TYPES.each_with_index do |association, index| %>
      <div id="profile_<%= association %>">
        <fieldset class="field-border">
          <legend class="field-border"><%= association.underscore %></legend>
            <%= f.fields_for :practice, build_builder_association(f, association) do |builder| %>
              <%= render "#{builder.object.class.name.underscore}_field", :f => builder %>
            <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

# helper
def build_builder_association(f, association)
  f.object.practice_type = association
  f.object.build_practice({})
end
```

Use Javascript to hide and show the templates based on an option selected from dropdown, and then when form is submitted, remove the hidden elements from the DOM:

```
    $("#new_lead").submit(function(){
        $("[id^='profile_']:hidden").remove();
    })
```

And that creates the original desired behavior I wanted. However, the solution is far from clean and any better suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I know this is old, but as it's near the top of my Google list, I'll comment here. Would it not have been sufficient to use locals? E.g. <%= render partial: "whatever", locals: { f: f } %>